# Set height of div equal to height of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been banging my head on this for a long time but can't seem to get it to work. I've read similar questions and tried their answers but they're not working for me so here I am.

I have a slider and it contains some  tags, I wanna set the container div's height equal to the height of the image. Firstly here's the html:

```
<section class="row" id="carousel">
    <ul class="rslideshow"> <!-- Images appear here -->
      <li><img src="../img/image1.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="../img/image2.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="../img/image3.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="../img/image4.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="../img/image5.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

This was the first code I tried:

```
function setHeight(ab){
        var heightImage = $('.rslideshow > li:first-child > img').height();
        ab.height(heightImage);
        console.log(heightImage);
    }
    setHeight($('.rslideshow'));
    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight($('.rslideshow'));
    });
```

The problem was that the image's height was being calculated to 0. The reason was document.ready triggers as soon as the DOM tree is ready. At this time, the images are not loaded yet. SO I tried delays with setTimeout but it didn't work and was not reliable anyway. Next, I tried using jquery's onLoad like this:

```
function setHeight(ab){
    var target = $('.rslideshow > li:first-child > img'),
        heightImage = 200;

    target.on('load', function(){
        heightImage = $(this).height();
        console.log(heightImage);
        ab.height(heightImage);
    });

}
setTimeout(setHeight($('.rslideshow')), 500);
$(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight($('.rslideshow'));
});
```

This on seemed to work but for some reason, onLoad doesn't trigger on window.resize. I also read on Jquery's website the onLoad is not reliable and cross browser.

So here is where I'm stuck. Any Ideas? I'm open to non javascript solutions too.

Comment: why can't you set the heights of the images since then you would already know it?

Comment: Don't use setTimeout..Instead write this code on window load (It will trigger only when images are loaded.)

Comment: try imagesloaded plugin if timing is an issue -- http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: @user2947 -- images load asynchronously and if you use the window load you may be waiting for sometime just to get 1 image size from the 10 you are loading

Comment: It can be reduced to just image load - $('.rslideshow > li:first-child > img').load(function () {
    console.log($(this).height());
};

Comment: @gurvinder372 The whole code is to make the slider responsive by height. When the viewport decreases, the image will contract keeping it's aspect-ratio. I'm trying to match the div's height to the images as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `complete` or `readyState` JavaScript attribute of the `img` element like the following code snippets.

```
$(function () {
    function setHeight(ab) {
        var target = $('.rslideshow > li:first-child > img'),
            heightImage;
        if (target[0].complete || target[0].readyState === 4) {
            heightImage = target.height();
            ab.height(heightImage);
        }
        else {
            target.on('load', function () {
                heightImage = $(this).height();
                console.log(heightImage);
                ab.height(heightImage);
            });
        }
    }
    setHeight($('.rslideshow'));
    $(window).resize(function () {
        setHeight($('.rslideshow'));
    });
});
```

**Explanation:**

[**complete**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp) - Returns whether or not the browser is finished loading an image.

**readyState** - While using [`Image Element constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) or triggering [`onreadystatechange`](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) event of AJAX, we can use `readyState` property. Please check the `readyState` details below.

```
State  Details

0      Request is not initialized
1      Connected with server
2      Request has been sent
3      Request is in process
4      Request is completed
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That works. So I assume onLoad doesn't gets triggered if the image is already loaded. Is that right? And would you explain your if statement? Why did you write "=== 4"? Why 4?

Comment: Yes `load` event will not trigger, if the image is loaded already. And for the `readyState` check the **Explanation** of answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation. Much Useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [at this pen](http://codepen.io/Fr33za/pen/MKMQQQ):

Html

```
<section class="row" id="carousel">
<ul class="rslideshow" stlye="list-style-type: none !important;"> <!-- Images appear here -->
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {

   setHeight($('.rslideshow'));  

})

function setHeight(ab) {
  var target = $('.rslideshow > li:first-child > img'),
    heightImage = 50;

  target.on('load', function() {
    ab.height(heightImage);
  });

}
$(window).resize(function() {
  setHeight($('.rslideshow'));
});
```

Note the use of the `$(window).load(function() {});`

This gets fired once all content on the dom is loaded, this means the images will exist before the script runs.

Also your 'setTimeout' method is incorrect. It needs to passed through a function eg:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    // Run timeout function here

}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `$('img').one()` to get the image `load` event callback and use `complete` attribute of img element in case the image is loaded from cache.

Example:

```
$(function(){
    //Page Loaded
  $("img").one("load", function() {
    //Image Loaded (Your handling here)
  }).each(function() {
    //Trigger Image load event if image already loaded when page loaded
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
});
```

JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5chcgbLc/2/